# UI automator / Has somebody faced problems with UI automator? (impossible to click on element)

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, automator, android-uiautomator

**Prehistory of my question:**

I'm studying UI automator (2.1.3) & Espresso tests + using android studio (3.0.1) on simple Mac Air (2014).
Previously I have created functional suite for test-run and it works fine for a long period of time.
But last week I have noticed strange behavior related to UI automator actions:
 - I can't perform single click on elements in my current project nor on android elements.
For example quite long period I have used click on element by ID in my project, but now these methods are non-functional.
Test has passed, but there is no result on screen and in app state, here is simple example:

```
 UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    String contentOfMyElement = "";
    UiObject myObject = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()
        .getString((R.id.idOfMyElement))).text(contentOfMyElement)
                    .clickable(true).checkable(false));
    mObject.click();
```

---

All objects of such structure suddenly became non-functional, tests are pass through and successful but nothing is going with app state.
Such structure has been functional for a long time in my project, but now all tests with it non-functional.

**I'm trying to resolve it in a next way:**

- first of all I though that something is wrong with mobile device so I have started several tests (with UI automator actions) on different devices (virtual and physical)
- clear android studio cache with restart
- sync gradle (which I haven't changed previously for a long time - 3 month or above) + clear my project + re-build it
- use previous version of UI automator in gradle dependencies
- re-install android studio

ALL of these items couldn't resolve issue which I have faced.
ADDITIONALLY I have tried above example in another android project and it non-functional too.

As I can see problems somewhere in UI automator or in the latest android studio 3.0.1
All I know for now - UI automator performing mDevice.pressHome(), back etc., but do not perform any actions on specific elements of my app.

**Does anybody know how to fix UI automator behavior?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug in android studio, can you get the correct "myObject"?
"myObject" will contain the bounds & locations of the element, "click()" action will perform one clicking at center location.

In the other hand, you are using uiautomator 2.0, you should ues UiObject2 instead of UiObject.

```
BySelector selector = By.res("resourceID");
UiObject2 obj = mDevice.findObject(selector);
```

Comment: Btw, UiObject2 do not allow you to use EXIST statement in branching condition, in my case it's not good.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have already resolved my issue. The only problem I have - cloned bug in UiObject structure, somehow I have cloned it via my project.

Answer (score 1):

So may be it will be useful for someone else, just remember UiObject should contain only one component identifier (UiObject do not allow to use component ID + component TEXT or descr no matter).

**Sample:**

```
UiObject myObject = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()
        .getString((R.id.idOfMyElement)))
        .clickable(true).checkable(false));
```

**OR**

```
 UiObject myObject = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()
        .text(contentOfMyElement)
        .clickable(true).checkable(false));
```